# What does "{True,True}" mean in the result of IntegrateChangeVariables?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to change variables in the following integral:

```
Integrate[q*D[z[x, y],x]^2, {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]
```

as follows:

```
{x == k1*x1, y == k1*y1}
```

and
`z[x,y]->k2*u[x1,y1]`

That is what I tried:

```
Simplify[
  IntegrateChangeVariables[
   Inactive[Integrate][
    q*D[z[x, y], 
      x]^2, {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞,
∞}], {x1, y1}, {x == k1*x1, y == k1*y1}], {x1 ∈ 
    Reals, y1 ∈ Reals, k1 > 0}] /. z -> (k2*u[#1/k1, #2/k1] &)
```

with the following effect:

[image]

This result is correct. However,
**my questions** are

1. Where the {True, True} comes from and what does it mean in this context?
2. Is it eventually possible to remove it?
3. Is it possible to change variables `z->u` within the function IntegrateChangeVariables, rather than as I did it?

Comment: The `{True, True}` comes from simplifying the 3rd argument in the code returned by `IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][
  q*D[z[x, y], x]^2,
  {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}
  ],
 {x1, y1},
 {x == k1*x1, y == k1*y1}]`.  That code seems erroneous to me (a bug, I mean). But the problem is better shown without the `Simplify`, imo.

Answer (score 0):

The following works well in 13.3.1 on Windows 10.

```
Assuming[k1 > 0, IntegrateChangeVariables[ Inactive[Integrate]
[ q*D[z[x, y],  x]^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], 
\[Infinity]}], {x1, y1}, {x == k1*x1, y == k1*y1}]]
```

> `k1^2*q*Integrate[Derivative[1, 0][z][ k1*x1, k1*y1]^2, {x1, -Infinity,  Infinity}, {y1, -Infinity,  Infinity}]`

Compare with a case of a specified `z[x,y]`

```
Assuming[k1 > 0, IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][q*D[Exp[-x^4 - y^2]
  , x]^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], {x1, y1}, 
{x == k1*x1, y == k1*y1}]]
```

> `Inactive[Integrate][(16*k1^8*q*x1^6)/ E^(2*k1^2*(k1^2*x1^4 + y1^2)),  {x1, -Infinity, Infinity},  {y1, -Infinity, Infinity}]`

One sees problems with the derivative in the general case.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know the answer to my first question? I would like to understand where this `{True,True}` comes from?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: No, I don't know answer to your first question. Ask  Mathematica developers that.